# PHPUnit - catch message from Throwable class

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony4

In my Symfony project, I am writing tests. I wrote all tests that are covering my `CustomException`. But, I want to write separate test to catch the one with `Throwable`. But, as all my cases are covered with `CustomException`, I do not know the way how to write a tests that will catch the message in `Throwable`.

From Controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/endpoint", methods={"POST"}, name="endpoint_name")
 */
public function someMethod($uuid)
 try {
        $this->myService->someServiceMethod($id);
        return $this->success("SUCCESS");
    } catch (CustomException $e) {
        return $this->handleCustomException($e);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        $this->logger->error("FAILED: " . $e->getMessage(), [
            $id
        ]);
        return $this->error("FAILED");
    }
```

Any thoughts?

```
public function testSomeMethod(): void
{
    $this->client->request(
        Request::METHOD_POST,
        self::API_URL . self::POST_ENDPOINT,
        [],
        [],
        [
            'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
            'ACCEPT' => 'application/json',
        ]
    );

    $response = $this->client->getResponse();
    $responseBody = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);

    $this->assertContains('Some message from Custom Exception!', $responseBody['error']);
    $this->assertEquals(405, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

This is the test for my Custom Exception that is working.
Is there any way I can wrote the same test but to catch the message from `Throwable` interface.

Comment: `Throwable` is not a class, but an interface. If no other exception is ever thrown, it's going to be hard for you to test that without mocking  `myService` so it throws an exception not covered by your first `catch` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replay! Can you give some detail input or example. @yivi

Comment: And yes, in this test case CustomException is thrown but never comes to Throwable interface.